# XOR MULTILAYER PERCEPTRON: how can one pass a subset of the training data as an argument to get there prediction value

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, xor

```
#imports
import tensorflow as tf
#Variables
hidden_layer1_node= 2
hidden_layer2_node= 1


X = tf.placeholder('float',[8,3])
Y = tf.placeholder('float',[8,1])

#neural model
def neural_model(x):
layer1_weight = {'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,hidden_layer1_node])),
                'bias':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_layer1_node]))}

layer2_weight = {'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,hidden_layer2_node])),
                'bias':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_layer2_node]))}


zl1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,layer1_weight['weight']), layer1_weight['bias'])
prediction1 = tf.sigmoid(zl1)

zl2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(prediction1,layer2_weight['weight']), layer2_weight['bias'])
return tf.sigmoid(zl2)

prediction = neural_model(X)


#cost function
def cost_function():
loss = tf.reduce_mean(-1*((Y*tf.log(prediction))+((1-Y)*tf.log(1.0-prediction))))
return loss

#Optimization
loss = cost_function()
training = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

#training stage
train_x = [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
train_y = [[0],[1],[1],[0],[1],[0],[0],[1]]
epoch = 10

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(epoch):
        for _ in range(5000):
            sess.run(training, feed_dict={X:train_x,Y:train_y})

        print(sess.run(loss,feed_dict={X:train_x,Y:train_y}))
    print(sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={X:train_x,Y:train_y}))
```

Based on the network model(assuming one understands) after it has been trained, How could you pass tensors of not just [8,3] but be able to pass [1,3] such as [0,0,1] or something. I guess I'm rephrasing my question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, TensorFlow doesn't allow the graph to change, that means that the input (and intermediate) tensors are required to have constant size. To distinguish between training and testing, you can use shared variables as explained here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variables#sharing_variables

Comment: Thank you. Now I managed to input data of the same tensor size. However I thought after the network is trained, you should get the same result regardless even if it is different sequence of inputs. By entering this I get different predictions. temp = tf.cast((tf.Variable([[0,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])),tf.float32)
tempInModel = neural_model(temp).    with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(tempInModel,feed_dict={X:train_x,Y:train_y}))

Comment: Please copy and past the above starting at the variable temp.Maybe I'm doing it wrong? Please help